# Why is debugging jsx in chrome so wonky?

Tags: reactjs

We're building a React/Flux application and everything is running and works fine, except the debugging experience is HORRIBLE in chrome!!

When trying to set breakpoints on legit lines like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(AccountInfo, null), document.getElementById('AccountInfoContainer'));
```

The breakpoint jumps down a few lines. Or it looks like the breakpoint is set properly, but when you run the page the breakpoint is no longer where you thought it was going to be.

We installed the React Dev tools, which gave us some nice functionality in a new tab "React" tab, but the standard "Sources" tab is just not working right.

We tried setting type="text/jsx" to see if Chrome would understand the file more correctly, but that resulted in the jsx file not even loading...could be the fault of IIS though not Chrome.

React seems so great, but it appears as though jsx really isn't supported all that well yet. Is there another chrome extension that will make jsx debugging work better?

We could also do server-side react rending and try to end up with a js file instead of jsx, but that seems like another can of worms...especially in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Are you using source maps? BTW, unrecognized script type attributes prevent them from loading, that's the expected browser behavior.

Comment: Not using source maps...I assume that would help? Any idea how I would generate those for a JSX file in MVC?

Comment: I though perhaps you might have bad source maps or something, but I guess that's not the case. Might be worth trying other browser debuggers, see how they behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any issues with the Chrome debugger and JSX as long as Source Maps have been generated.

[image]

You may notice I am also using ES6 in this screenshot, also without any issue.

Comment: Ya we decided to transpile the jsx to js, everything is working good. Maps would have helped too